# Tree of a kind split confusion

Tags: 3-of-a-kind

I was playing poker with my friends and we came across this situation that created some confusion. So the context was like this:

- one guy had: 7 3 off suite
- the second guy had: 7 6 off suite

cards on table: 7 7 Q 9 4

What happens in this scenario and why?

My opionion is that this is a split, since the best cards are: 7 7 7 Q 9, and the kicker doesn't count in this situation. Any other opinions?

Comment: Yes your opinion here is fact and this is a split pot.

Comment: The non-playing hole card shouldn't be referred to as a "kicker".  The kickers in this hand are the Q and the 9.